# how to get the output of this SQL query in python language

Tags: python, sql

```
SELECT * FROM Sales where SKUDESC='samsung' AND Full_month='January'
```

i want output which this query gives but in python code

i am trying to groupby and i am getting name of groups .how to get values like it gives in SQL query

```
field=['product', 'month']
grouped=df.groupby(field).groups
```

Comment: show the python details code

Comment: There is no groupby in your sql query, why would you use groupby in youpython code?

Comment: i dont want to groupby  i was trying groupby function to get same output as the query but its not working    new_df = df.loc[(df.SKUDESC == 'samsung') & (df.Full_month == 'January')]   this is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales where SKUDESC='samsung' AND Full_month='January'
```

Python:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df.SKUDESC == 'samsung') & (df.Full_month == 'January')]
```

Comment: thanks it works .now i am trying to pass the variable in which samsung and january are stored i did this for sql query and it wored        query="SELECT * FROM"+" "+ tablename+" "+ "where"+" " + field[0]+"="+"'"+values[0]+"'" +" "+ "AND" + " " +field[1]+"="+ "'"+values[1]
    query=query+ "'"
print(query)                    but when i am doing it in this code its not working i want to pass the variable          new_dfq = "(df."+field[0]+" == "+"'"+values[0]+"'"+ ") & (df." + field[1]+ " =="+"'"+ values[1]+"'"+")"
print(new_dfq)

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear and difficult to comprehend. Perhaps you can post another question in a clear manner so that someone can help you.

Comment: Also, if I understand you are trying to dynamically get the column name, I guess it should be something like df[(field[0]] == values[0]) & (field[1]] == values[1])]. Please try it.

Comment: okay forget it, the simple queston is  that can i pass the variable in this df.loc function in which samsung and january are stored. i am trying but its not working

Comment: yes i am trying to dynamically get the column name and this is not working some key error

Comment: Did you try the one I posted in the comments, that should work if values[0] equals samsung, and field[0] equals SKUDESC, likewise for the other one.

Comment: yes i tried and its showing key error ,values are there in field and values variable

Answer (score 0):

You can import the output of query in python dataframe like below.

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(query ,columns=[‘col_1’, ‘col_2’])
```